# Please explain the below JavaScript code which returns the value of the unpaired element from the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, xor

Below is the working code which returns the value 7 from the array [9, 3, 9, 7, 3, 9, 9], because 7 is the value that does not have the same pair, all other values except 7 have a similar value pair in the array.

But I didn't understand this code, can someone please explain this code line by line. Please...

```
function check(array) {
        var s = new Set;
        
        array.forEach(v => s.delete(v) || s.add(v));
        
        return s.values().next().value;
    }
    
    console.log(check([9, 3, 9, 7, 3, 9, 9]));
```

Comment: Better: `array.forEach(v => s.has(v) ? s.delete(v) : s.add(v));`

Comment: Also more readable as `let [value] = s; return value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is creating a set first, then, for each element in the array, it checks if that exists in the set, if it does, it removes it from the set (thus, removing a pair)

when it does not find, then it stores, for it to wait for the next pair

a simulation here with an array of 5 elements

```js
array = [1,3,3,2,1]

//first iteration
v = 1
set = [1]

//next iteration
v = 3
set = [1,3]

//next iteration
v = 3
set = [1] // the 3 was deleted

//next iteration
v = 2
set = [1,2]

//next iteration
v = 1
set = [2] // 1 was deleted
```

at the end, it gets the element alone in the set (or the first one)

so a run with an array `[4,4,4]` will return `4` as the last element has no pair

Answer (score 1):

A Set only contains a value one time, the code is looping in the Array elements and try to delete the value from the Set it exists if not it added it to the Set, at the Set finished with the elements that only exists one time in the Array